# How can I make a dynamic dropdowns in a Struts 2 using a Map object in an Action class?

Tags: struts2, populate, struts-tags, double-select

In an `Action` class I have `Map<String, List<String>> countryMap`.

Let's say the `key` of `countryMap` are the letters of the alphabet and the value are the Country objects that starts with the corresponding key.

For example:

**Key:** `A`

**Value:** List contains `Australia, Angola, Algeria`, etc.

I want to make two dynamic dropdowns in Struts 2.

Dropdown 1 looks something like:

```html
 <select>
     <option value="A">A</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
 </select>
```

In dropdown two will show the value depending the key on dropwdown 1. For example, I chose A in dropdown 1, the dropwdown will populate the values.

Dropdown 2 looks something like:

```html
<select>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
</select>
```

I'm thinking of using `<s:select>` tag of Struts 2. I don't know how to start. I'm not well-versed with these functionalities. With this complicated code, I might need JavaScript involvement. I'm having a hard time starting developing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making two tags to communicate with each other **on the same page** is impossible without javascript. Fortunately there's Struts2 `doubleselect` tag that can be use in that scenario.

> It renders two HTML select elements with second one changing displayed values depending on selected entry of first one.

```jsp
<s:doubleselect label="Select country/state" name="country" list="{'country1','other'}" doubleName="state" doubleList="top == 'country1' ? {'state1', 'state2'} : {'state3', 'state4'}" />
```

For the real example see [Struts 2 `<s:doubleselect>` example](https://www.w3schools.blog/struts-2-sdoubleselect-ui-tag).

Comment: It's *not* submit, and it's making another request the URL might be the same but the page count will be different.